# jQuery Asynchrony Condition Statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

In jQuery, can you do something like this:

```
function f(b) { 
    return $("<input></input>")
        .addClass("test")
        .if(b, function() {
            $(this).attr("disabled", true).addClass("example");
        })
        .val("test");
}
```

instead of:

```
function f(b) {
    var input = $("<input></input>").addClass("test");

    if (b) {
        input.attr("disabled", true).addClass("example");
    }

    return input.val("test");
}
```

?

It's just a syntactic sugar, actually. A useful one, though. Especially while authoring large Ajax applications.

Is this feature planned for next versions or something?

Comment: stackoverflow is not a feature-request site. Go and file a bug if you want this feature.

Comment: I think it's a reasonable question nontheless.

Comment: this is not a feature request. I just asked if there's such existing feature.

Answer (score 1):

See this [chainable iif](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-iff-plugin/) plugin by Ben Alman.

Example

```
$('div')
  .append( '1' )
  .iff( my_test, 'foo' )
    .append( '2' )
    .end()
  .append( '3' );
```

Another way is as a commentator to the above post explains [here](http://jethrolarson.blogspot.com/2008/12/using-ternary-to-choose-between-two.html)

Example

```
$(this)[$(this).hasClass("myClass")?"hide":"show"]();
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no "conditional" method or something. I don't think a method like that will make it into the core, it's pretty much like overkill isn't it? Example:

```
function f( b ) {
    return $( '<input>', {
        'class':    'test',
        disabled:   !!b,   // alternate: b === 'something' ? true : false
        value:      'test'
    });
}
```

That would just bend that `b` variable into a boolean value and pass it to the `disable attribute`. I guess you can create similar construct on all occasions where such a method like `.if()` could be useful.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/L8ZaP/

Answer (score 1):

I think this doesn't look worse:

```
function f(b) { 
    return $("<input></input>")
        .addClass("test")            
        .attr("disabled", b ? true : false)
        .addClass(b ? "example" : "")
        .val("test");
}
```

Comment: but what about the `.addClass("example")`?

Comment: @Alon, What is wrong about addClass? In my example this looks like this: `addClass(b ? "example" : "")`